# OpenCV Python resize image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am trying to resize an contour to 28x28 pixels and to pass it through my model to detect the digit and display it.
However, I have a problem with function `cv2.resize()`.
Here's my code:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret == False:
    continue
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

# Threshold the image
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 4)

# Find contours in the image
_, contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


# ******************************************************************* #
# Get rectangles contains each contour
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in contours]

for rect in rects:
    # Draw the rectangles
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3) 

    # Make the rectangular region around the digit
    leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
    pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
    pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)

    height, width = frame.shape[:2]

    if pt1+leng > width or pt2+leng > height:
        continue;

    roi = frame[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]

    # Resize the image
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), cv2.INTER_AREA)
    roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))

    #nbr = clf.predict(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
    #cv2.putText(frame, str(int(nbr)), (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.putText(frame, "2", (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

The error I am getting is:

> error:
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044:
>   error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function
>   cv::resize

Resizing the original frame of the video (without any other cv2 function applied on it before) is doing well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `roi` is empty...

Comment: Okay, why is it empty?

Comment: The problem is that pt2 and pt1 from time to time are negative and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try defining a threshold for your contour areas with `cv2.contourArea(ctr)`. So you are saying that the contours needs to be at least a certain size.

Comment: Just enforce that the points are bounded. Take the max with the coordinates and 0. Take the min with the points and the image size. Now your bounding box coordinates won't go outside the image bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was trying to get coordinate picture that were negative so it couldn't get it. I just expanded condition `if pt1+leng > width or pt2+leng > height or pt2 < 0 or pt1 < 0:` and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a copy of the roi before attempting to resize,

```
roiImg = roi.copy()
roiImg = cv2.resize(roiImg, (28, 28), cv2.INTER_AREA)
```